# bash for loop with unknown array

Tags: bash, array

I need to execute a for loop over the elements in array edg_cdi, but I know it is that array just because my input parameter is chosen='cdi'. If it was chosen='cdt' (or many others) the selected array would be different.

```
chosen='cdi'

edg_cdi=('40' '46' '37' '43')
edg_cdt=('69' '24' '177' '25')

string='edg_'
wholename=$string$chosen

for i in "${ WHAT_TO_WRITE_HERE [@]}"
do
  echo $i
done
```

The desired output is four echos:

```
40
46
37
43
```

Comment: when you say the "selected array would be different" you mean an array with different data or a different type, like a simple variable? Anyway for the code you provide for cycle substitute "WHAT_TO_WRITE_HERE" with ${wholename[@]}

Comment: @Pimp Juice IT. The issue is I don't know the variable name. After knowing chosen='cdi', I can get wholename='edg_cdi'. But "${wholename[@]}" won't work.

Comment: @AtomiX84 The output of
 for i in "${wholename[@]}" is wrong: It's edg_cdi, when it shoud be 40 46 37 43.

Comment: This question is maybe a duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820343/how-can-i-generate-new-variable-names-on-the-fly-in-a-shell-script#10820494. Anyway I have fixed your code using the accepted answer there and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variable indirection with a proper array (unlike @user1330614's answer, which fakes an array with a plain variable). The tricky thing is that you have to include the array element (or `[@]` for all elements) in the variable you're indirecting through. Like this:

```
edg_cdi=('40' '46' '37' '43')
wholename="edg_cdi"             # Same value original code generates
wholearray="${wholename}[@]"    # This includes the array name AND "[@]"
for i in "${!wholearray}"; do
    #...etc
```

To get e.g. the n'th element of the array, you could use something like:

```
n=3    # The element number we want
wholename_n="${wholename}[n]"    # Note that n does not have a $; it won't be resolved until use
dosomethingwith "${!wholename_n}"    # this resolves n and gets the 3rd element
n=2
dosomethingwith "${!wholename_n}"    # this re-resolves n and gets the 2nd element
```

Comment: Now this is *the* answer! I was going to publish a solution based on `declare -p`. I thought it was decent, I still do; but yours is so much better there's no point in publishing my inferior one. My test array is like `edg_cdi=('normal' 'with space' 'double"quote' "single'quote" $'new-\n-line' '\backslash')`, your code handles it flawlessly. Good job!

Comment: Additional reading on the topic with further examples and explanation for those that need even additional clarity perhaps..... [Indirect References](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) and [Indirect variable references - the new way](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html#EX78)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this

```
chosen='cdi'

edg_cdi="40 46 37 43"
edg_cdt="69 24 177 25"

string='edg_'
wholename=$string$chosen

for i in ${!wholename}
do
  echo $i
done
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820343/how-can-i-generate-new-variable-names-on-the-fly-in-a-shell-script#10820494)

Comment: @Uxio Here's another related post that gives more detail about Variable Indirection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean too.

Comment: @user1330614 Thank you for your reply, but, I think it is not working properly: The output of this answer is a single row: '40 46 37 43', a single echo.

I need $i to be 40, then 46, then 37 and then 43.

In this solution, edg_cdi is treated as a single string, but its required to be a set (array) of four independent elements, where the for loop can process independently.

Comment: I've tested the code myself and it outputs 40 46 37 and 43                                                                                                                                                                                in separated rows.

Comment: Make sure you don't enclose  ${!wholename} between ""

Comment: @user1330614 Oh, sorry! True! Regards, thank you for your help.

Comment: Nice @Uxio. If it work for you please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1330614 23 Done